# Angular-gettext doesn't update strings generated in code

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-gettext

When I set language like this `gettextCatalog.setCurrentLanguage(langString);` it doesn't work to my side-nav menu. My side menu can be in one of two states: expanded or collapsed, so I use ng-include for side menu and change it when switching states.

When I use `setCurrentLanguage`, strings inside menu don't change. It will be changed only after page reloading (I keep current language in localStorage). So, `setCurrentLanguage` could be applied on app startup  to my side menu, but it doesn't work dynamically.

**Edit:**

Probably it is connected with that fact that I generate menu item's names using `gettextCatalog.getString('somestring')`, so, names will be created with correct languages at startup, but I can't update them when changing languages, because the result of `gettextCatalog.getString('somestring') is just stored in variable now. So, no angular watchers there anymore.

So, how to update strings that created from code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `gettextCatalog.getString()`, use `gettext()` instead:

```
$scope.myVar = gettext("Something");
```

And in your view, use the `translate` filter:

```
{{ myVar | translate}}
```

This will correctly update when you change the language.

More info here: https://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/dev-guide/annotate-js/